# CSS Pie making page load very slowly in IE8

Tags: css, css3pie

I am using pie.htc to allow me to have radius corners and drop shadows on my website in old versions of IE.

The trouble is it seems to be making IE run very very slowly.

Here's an example of my code... can anyone see how I can improve this?

```
div.myDiv {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;    
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: I would actually recommend you not to use CSS3 Pie, it's better to just leave out the rounded corners or work with images. My experience with CSS3 pie is that it always takes a while for it to load or sometimes needs a refresh to work properly. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You don't need any of these vendor prefixes

Answer (score 2):

I used CSS3Pie a lot in projects, because I *was forced to* make the sites *exactly look alike* which of course is nonsense in for a technician, but not a sales guy.

Actually, using any kind of `.htc` files is very slow because pie needs to parse these rules and create according VML-Elements to emulate the according css3-behaviour. If you have bigger projects you will have no choice other than:

- Completely omitting CSS3-features for IE8 (and convince your salesguy) <- my favorite option
- Omitting pie and using IE filters wherever possible
- using a more lightweight framework with lesser support but faster processing, because PIE is (because it has such a superb support) quite bloated and thus rather slow

Using positions like Razor adviced does not really fix the speed issue and prefixing with `-ms` might give you serious trouble in IE9 trying to use both, css3pie and the prefixed css3-property.

Answer (score 0):

try this for a change

```
div.myDiv 
{
  border-radius: 5px; 
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;    
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -ms-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);      
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
  position:relative;
}
```

PIE.htc file loads asynchronously along with DOM when it is ready. Setting the `position:relative` can certainly give you an edge. i prefix `-ms-` in code snippet which helps to detect IE. it worked for me. i used latest PIE.htc file.